# Does the archiving mechanism in content repository impact the performance of workflows?

Tags: apache-nifi

We are actually studying how NiFi's Content Repository Archiving works.

We got information from the following webpage : https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/82308/understanding-how-nifis-content-repository-archivi.html

Unfortunately, we still have questions and I need some help getting their answers :

- Are there still "content claims" if archiving is disabled?
- If archiving is disabled, does this mean that the purge mechanism of the content of the flowfiles will not occur?
- Does the archiving mechanism have an impact on disks (I/O) and therefore on performance? So, if we unable it, will we have a significant gain?

Until now, the archiving mechanism is enabled.

Then I need to adapt the parameters for my usage : We are using NIFI for a single use case, with an estimated target throughput of 50000 msg/s.

We have 3 nodes => each node process nearly 17000 msg/s per Node

Each message is sized about 810 bytes. With the help of the "record" type processors, we build flowfiles composed of 1000 messages, very early in the workflow that we have.

So Each flowfile is size 810 KB.

17000 msg/s per Node = 17 flowfiles/s per Node = nearly 14 Mo/s per Node.

We know that we need to change the following parameters :

nifi.content.claim.max.appendable.size=10 MB (default value)
nifi.content.claim.max.flow.files=100 (default value)

But my questions are : What's the best values for our use case? Is there a way to determine the right values? to calculate them?

I have the feeling that if I put low values, there will be more I/O. 
If I put higher values, the data resides in queue inside NIFI, waiting for the content claim to fill up. So the memory usage (maybe the swap) will increase...

Answer (score 1):

When a content claim in the content repo has no more file files referencing it, then that content claim is eligible for removal. You can think of the clean up process like Java garbage collection where it periodically removes stuff from the heap that is no longer actively referenced.

If archiving is enabled then it archives the content claim so that the data is retained for later use, such as viewing provenance events that point to old content. It will be retained according to the settings in nifi.properties. When archiving is disabled, the content claim is removed as soon as it can be.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/nifi-in-depth.html

Comment: Thank you Bryan. Does this archiving mecanism generate additional I/O on disks ? I mean : is it an "all in memory" mecanism and the content claim is persisted on disks when the content claim is complete? or all the flowfiles' content are written on disks but the content claim is removed once complete? If I disable archiving, will I reduce my disk usage? I learned that finally, the main critical point in NIFI  is the I/O in flowfile, content and provenance repositories.

Comment: The content of a flow file is never held in memory in NiFi, it is all pass by reference. It is only read in from content repo when a processor needs to access the content, and even though it should be read in a streaming fashion, unless the processor cannot do this for some reason (ex EvaluateJsonPath must read whole content into memory).

Comment: Archiving shouln't impact I/O, but it will impact disk space usage. If it is enabled then it will use more disk, disabled less disk.

Comment: See Content Repo section here for how to setup multiple partitions of the content repo on different disks - https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/7882/hdfnifi-best-practices-for-setting-up-a-high-perfo.html

Comment: late for the party. but you can configure the content repository to use memory ( nifi.content.repository.implementation=org.apache.nifi.controller.repositoryVolatileContentRepository

Comment: If you use in-memory content repository, then if nifi restarts, the content of all flow files currently in the flow is lost.